# Find Thevenin equivalent voltage - Circuit Analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin, kirchhoffs-laws

[image: Circuit]

I am trying to understand how to calculate Vth (between the blue Volt meter and the grey volt meter).

I have calculated the current correctly using KVL. However, I can't find a way to calculate Vth. According to the simulator the result is: -7.746v but I do not know how to get to this result.

Comment: With such simple circuit featuring 3 sources, I would apply superposition to determine \$V_{th}\$: calculate \$V_{th1}\$ for \$V_1\$ and \$V_2\$ reduced to 0 V (shorted) while \$I_1\$ is alive, then \$V_{th2}\$ for \$I_1\$ (0 A, open) and \$V_2\$ off (0 V, short circuit) \$V_1\$ is alive and finally \$V_{th3}\$ for \$I_1\$ (0 A, open) and \$V_1\$ off (0 V, short circuit), \$V_2\$ is alive. The Thévenin voltage you want is the sum of these three intermediate steps.

Comment: @VerbalKint
Thank you very much!  That worked!
I also managed to calculate it using KVL.

Comment: @TalJ Please accept the answer below so that this question can be closed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With such simple circuit featuring 3 sources, I would apply superposition to determine \$V_{th}\$: calculate \$V_{th1}\$ for \$V_1\$ and \$V_2\$ reduced to 0 V (shorted) while \$I_1\$ is alive, then \$V_{th2}\$ for \$I_1\$ (0 A, open) and \$V_2\$ off (0 V, short circuit) \$V_1\$ is alive and finally \$V_{th3}\$ for \$I_1\$ (0 A, open) and \$V_1\$ off (0 V, short circuit), \$V_2\$ is alive. The Thévenin voltage you want is the sum of these three intermediate steps.